# db2_install do not have write permission on the directory or file

Tags: db2, permissions, installation, redhat

This is the error I encountered (I ran the `db2_install` and everything else as root,):

```
DBI1288E  The execution of the program /home/DB_SERVER/ibm/db2/v10.5 failed. This
      program failed because you do not have write permission on the
      directory or file .
```

I tried to change the access permission of the path:

```
chmod -R a+rw /home/DB_SERVER/ibm/db2/v10.5
```

And then I could create a new file in that folder:

```
vi test
```

Result of `ll` in that directory:

```
total 1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 12 Nov 23 00:24 test
```

But when I ran the `db2_install` again, it failed for the same reason.

PS: I tried to change permission of the setup file too

```
chmod -R a+rwx db2Setup/
```

Result of `ll`

```
total 72
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root 4096 Nov 23 00:10 db2
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5349 Nov 23 00:10 db2ckupgrade
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5302 Nov 23 00:10 db2_deinstall
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5172 Nov 23 00:10 db2_install
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5136 Nov 23 00:10 db2ls
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5154 Nov 23 00:10 db2prereqcheck
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5154 Nov 23 00:10 db2setup
drwxrwxrwx 10 root root 4096 Nov 23 00:10 ibm_im
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 5190 Nov 23 00:10 installFixPack
drwxrwxrwx  4 root root 4096 Nov 23 00:10 nlpack
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    8 Nov 23 01:00 test
```

So I have no idea what's wrong? How to fix this?

Comment: In our case we have permissions 750 and the folder permissions set at root:system. See if that helps.

Comment: Thank for the suggestions, that means run 2 commands : `chmod 750 path` and `chown -R root:system path`? `root:system` is a bit new with me.

Comment: The error message looks a bit weird. What was the exact command that you ran (copy/paste if you can)?

Comment: @mustaccio You mean the command to start the setup? It just an executable: `db2_install`.

Comment: Is the directory you are installing from or to on an NFS filesystem?  If so this may cause problems if you don't have proper NFS options (i.e. disable `root_squash`).

Comment: Here is a result of `fdisk -l` . I'm not really familiar with red hat partitions thing:  <br/>  `Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        5222    41430016   8e  Linux LVM`

Comment: So sorry for the bad format. I don't know how to fix this :p

Answer (score 0):

if you install on mounted fs ensure it's not mounted with the nosuid and noexec parameters.

db2 binaries require suid file permissions.

remove v10.5 directory if you created it manually

and set chmod 755 on parent directory

Answer (score -1):

We had similar kind of issue and this was fixed after we ran fsck. 
Note:- We ran FSck after we reboot the server. You might try it.